# Can I dynamically change the font size of a dialog window created with C++ in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fonts, dialog, font-size

Say, if I'm creating a dialog window from a resource in a C++/MFC project with Visual Studio, I can change the dialog box font and size from the resource editor. My question is how to do the same from a program?

Here's a couple of screenshots:

Regular size:
[image]

Size 14:
[image]

PS. I can imagine that once the dialog window is created one won't be able to change the font size, but what about before it's created?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NikBougalis: Give end-user control to enlarge or shrink the window. Sometimes also the window is too large for an end-user's display size, so I can shrink the font automatically. And there's a ton of other uses... I'm surprised that you even ask this question.

Comment: You will have a hard time achieving this with dialogs. Reflowing all the controls isn't a big deal. But calculating the appropriate font size so that text isn't clipped and lines up will be. If you want this type of "reflowing" UI, then dialogs aren't what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I had no idea that it's so complicated. Here's the solution I came up with to change font size and font face. It works for any dialog without resizing of individual dialog controls:

[image]

For MFC project:

```
//Header .h file
static INT_PTR OpenDialogWithFont(CWnd* pParentWnd, LPCTSTR lpszResourceID, LPCTSTR pstrFontFaceName = NULL, WORD wFontPtSz = 0, BOOL* pbOutResultFontApplied = NULL);
static BYTE* AdvanceThrough_sz_Or_Ord(BYTE* pData);
static BYTE* AdvanceThrough_String(BYTE* pData, CString* pOutStr = NULL);
```

Then the implementation itself:

```
INT_PTR OpenDialogWithFont(CWnd* pParentWnd, LPCTSTR lpszResourceID, LPCTSTR pstrFontFaceName, WORD wFontPtSz, BOOL* pbOutResultFontApplied)
{
    //Open dialog box with the 'lpszResourceID'
    //'pParentWnd' = parent window class
    //'pstrFontFaceName' = Font face name to use, or NULL to use original font
    //'wFontPtSz' = point size of the font, or 0 to use original font size
    //'pbOutResultFontApplied' = if not NULL, receives TRUE if font was applied, or FALSE if dialog was shown with original font
    //RETURN:
    //      = One of the values returned by CDialog::DoModal
    INT_PTR nResDlg = -1;

    BOOL bAppliedFont = FALSE;
    BYTE* pCNewData = NULL;

    LPCTSTR m_lpszTemplateName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(lpszResourceID);
    HINSTANCE hInst = AfxFindResourceHandle(m_lpszTemplateName, RT_DIALOG);
    if(hInst)
    {
        HRSRC hResource = ::FindResource(hInst, m_lpszTemplateName, RT_DIALOG);
        HGLOBAL hDialogTemplate = LoadResource(hInst, hResource);
        if(hDialogTemplate)
        {
            LPCDLGTEMPLATE lpDialogTemplate = (LPCDLGTEMPLATE)LockResource(hDialogTemplate);
            DWORD dwszDialogTemplate = SizeofResource(hInst, hResource);
            if(lpDialogTemplate &&
                dwszDialogTemplate)
            {
                //Template to use
                LPCDLGTEMPLATE lpDialogTemplateToUse = lpDialogTemplate;

                //See if it's an extended dialog structure
                DLGTEMPLATEEX_PART1* pDTX1 = (DLGTEMPLATEEX_PART1*)lpDialogTemplate;
                if(pDTX1->signature == 0xFFFF &&
                    pDTX1->dlgVer == 1)
                {
                    //Now get thru variable length elements
                    BYTE* pData = (BYTE*)(pDTX1 + 1);

                    //sz_Or_Ord menu;
                    pData = AdvanceThrough_sz_Or_Ord(pData);

                    //sz_Or_Ord windowClass;
                    pData = AdvanceThrough_sz_Or_Ord(pData);

                    //title
                    CString strTitle;
                    pData = AdvanceThrough_String(pData, &strTitle);

                    //Now pointsize of the font
                    //This member is present only if the style member specifies DS_SETFONT or DS_SHELLFONT.
                    if(pDTX1->style & (DS_SETFONT | DS_SHELLFONT))
                    {
                        //Font size in pts
                        BYTE* pPtr_FontSize = pData;
                        WORD ptFontSize = *(WORD*)pData;
                        pData += sizeof(WORD);

                        WORD wFontWeight = *(WORD*)pData;
                        pData += sizeof(WORD);

                        BYTE italic = *(BYTE*)pData;
                        pData += sizeof(BYTE);

                        BYTE charset = *(BYTE*)pData;
                        pData += sizeof(BYTE);

                        //Font face name
                        CString strFontFaceName;
                        BYTE* pPtr_FontFaceName = pData;
                        pData = AdvanceThrough_String(pData, &strFontFaceName);

                        //Remember the end of the struct (that we care about)
                        BYTE* pPtr_EndStruct = pData;

                        //Get size of the end data chunk
                        int ncbszEndChunk = dwszDialogTemplate - (pPtr_EndStruct - (BYTE*)lpDialogTemplate);
                        if(ncbszEndChunk >= 0)
                        {
                            //Now we can modify the struct

                            //Get new type face name (or use the old one)
                            CString strNewFontFaceName = pstrFontFaceName ? pstrFontFaceName : strFontFaceName;

                            //Calculate the new struct size
                            int ncbSzNewData = dwszDialogTemplate - 
                                strFontFaceName.GetLength() * sizeof(WCHAR) + 
                                strNewFontFaceName.GetLength() * sizeof(WCHAR);

                            //Reserve mem
                            pCNewData = new BYTE[ncbSzNewData];
                            if(pCNewData)
                            {
                                BYTE* pNewData = pCNewData;

                                //Copy in chunks
                                memcpy(pNewData, lpDialogTemplate, pPtr_FontFaceName - (BYTE*)lpDialogTemplate);
                                pNewData += pPtr_FontFaceName - (BYTE*)lpDialogTemplate;

                                //Then put our font face name
                                memcpy(pNewData, strNewFontFaceName.GetString(), (strNewFontFaceName.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
                                pNewData += (strNewFontFaceName.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

                                //And add the ending chunk
                                memcpy(pNewData, pPtr_EndStruct, ncbszEndChunk);
                                pNewData += ncbszEndChunk;

                                //Check memory allocation
                                if(pNewData - pCNewData == ncbSzNewData)
                                {
                                    //Are we setting the font size?
                                    if(wFontPtSz != 0)
                                    {
                                        WORD* pwFontSz = (WORD*)(pCNewData + (pPtr_FontSize - (BYTE*)lpDialogTemplate));
                                        if(*pwFontSz != wFontPtSz)
                                        {
                                            //Set flag
                                            bAppliedFont = TRUE;
                                        }

                                        //Set new font size
                                        *pwFontSz = wFontPtSz;
                                    }

                                    //Did we have a specified font face too
                                    if(pstrFontFaceName)
                                        bAppliedFont = TRUE;

                                    //Use our adjusted template
                                    lpDialogTemplateToUse = (LPCDLGTEMPLATE)pCNewData;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ASSERT(NULL);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                //Try to load it from the template
                CDialog abt;
                if(abt.InitModalIndirect(lpDialogTemplateToUse, pParentWnd))
                {
                    //And show the modal dialog
                    nResDlg = abt.DoModal();
                }

            }
        }

    }


    //Free memory
    if(pCNewData)
    {
        delete[] pCNewData;
        pCNewData = NULL;
    }

    if(pbOutResultFontApplied)
        *pbOutResultFontApplied = bAppliedFont;

    return nResDlg;
}
```

Custom struct definition:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // exact fit - no padding
struct DLGTEMPLATEEX_PART1{
  WORD      dlgVer;
  WORD      signature;
  DWORD     helpID;
  DWORD     exStyle;
  DWORD     style;
  WORD      cDlgItems;
  short     x;
  short     y;
  short     cx;
  short     cy;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Here's aux methods for parsing variable-size members:

```
BYTE* AdvanceThrough_sz_Or_Ord(BYTE* pData)
{
    //'pData' = Points to a variable-length array of 16-bit elements that identifies a menu 
    //          resource for the dialog box. If the first element of this array is 0x0000, 
    //          the dialog box has no menu and the array has no other elements. If the first 
    //          element is 0xFFFF, the array has one additional element that specifies the 
    //          ordinal value of a menu resource in an executable file. If the first element 
    //          has any other value, the system treats the array as a null-terminated Unicode 
    //          string that specifies the name of a menu resource in an executable file.
    //RETURN:
    //      = Following address
    ASSERT(pData);

    WORD* pWArr = (WORD*)pData;
    if(*pWArr == 0x0000)
    {
        //No other elements
        pWArr++;
    }
    else if(*pWArr == 0xFFFF)
    {
        //Next element is menu ID
        pWArr++;
        pWArr++;
    }
    else
    {
        //Unicode ASIIZ string
        WCHAR z;
        do
        {
            z = *pWArr;
            pWArr++;
        }
        while(z != 0);
    }

    return (BYTE*)pWArr;
}

BYTE* AdvanceThrough_String(BYTE* pData, CString* pOutStr)
{
    //'pData' = Points to null-terminated Unicode string
    //'pOutStr' = if not NULL, receives the string scanned
    //RETURN:
    //      = Pointer to the first BYTE after the string
    ASSERT(pData);

    WCHAR* pWStr = (WCHAR*)pData;
    WCHAR z;
    do
    {
        z = *pWStr;
        pWStr++;
    }
    while(z != 0);

    if(pOutStr)
    {
        int nLn = pWStr - (WCHAR*)pData;
        memcpy(pOutStr->GetBufferSetLength(nLn), pData, nLn * sizeof(WCHAR));
        pOutStr->ReleaseBuffer();
    }

    return (BYTE*)pWStr;
}
```

And here's how you call it:

```
BOOL bResAppliedFontCorrection;
int nResultDlg = OpenDialogWithFont(this, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX),
    _T("Algerian"), 
    16, 
    &bResAppliedFontCorrection);
```

For those who's interested how it works, the method modifies the [dialog template structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before creating the dialog and thus letting OS do all the font manipulations.

Comment: Just curious, why didn't you just apply this font for each child control? Wouldn't that have been so much easier?

Comment: @AnishRam: Doing so as you said would involve resizing and repositioning of all of the controls, as well as the parent window itself due to the font size change. Doing that would be a **major** headache.

Comment: That's a great solution, thanks.  There is, however, a bug.  The data after the font face must be aligned on a 4-byte boundary.  So if the old font face is an odd number of 16-bit characters, you must discard 2 bytes of padding.  And if the new font face is an odd number of 16-bit characters, you must add 2 bytes of padding.

Comment: One more thing, be aware the .rc file must declare the dialog as "DIALOGEX" and not "DIALOG".

Answer (score 3):

Have not tested this, but it seems like you could use WinAPI `SendDlgItemMessage`:

```
hFont = // obtain handle to a font object
SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_OF_YOUR_CONTROL, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfFont, TRUE);
```

Replacing `IDC_OF_YOUR_CONTROL` with the dialag's identifier. Example code to create a 12pt "Times New Roman" font:

```
HFONT hf;
HDC hdc;
long lfHeight;

hdc = GetDC(NULL);
lfHeight = -MulDiv(12, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);

hf = CreateFont(lfHeight, 0, 0, 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Times New Roman");
```

Source: http://winprog.org/tutorial/fonts.html

**Edit**: I don't know how these WinAPI calls map onto MFC, but there are probably similar methods available.

Comment: -1. This would work on per-control basis and would be a major pain-in-the-*ss to apply to different dialogs.

Answer (score -1):

As I noted in my comment, what you are trying to do isn't going to be particularly easy. There's many corner cases and small things that will come back to bite you.

However, if you want to try it anyways, you can change the font of the dialogs' child windows using [CWnd::SetFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y64cf7e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Simply construct the font you want to use, assign it to the appropriate controls, and tada.

Good luck...